# Async URLClassLoader throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'm trying to asynchronously load class files, but it seems every time I try to do it async, it throws a ClassNotFoundException.

Looking through the source for the class, ClassLoader should work async (It synchronizes itself), yet I only get the problem when I load a class from a different thread than where the URLClassLoader was created.

Example:
Thread 1 loads the URLs and creates the URLClassLoader
Thread 2 uses the URLClassLoader to load my/example/Foo.class. It passes my.example.Foo to ClassLoader#loadClass(String), and a ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

Example code:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(myJarURLs, getClass().getClassLoader());
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
    loader.loadClass("my.example.Foo")
}, executor);
executor.shutdown();
```

I know my code works, it works fine when it all runs on one thread.

Comment: You’re better off setting the class loader for the thread in a custom thread factory. This code yields confusing behaviour because the class loader of the thread is different to the class loader you’re trying to use to load classes.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of a custom thread factory, what would that look like? I was unaware classloaders were thread-specific.

Comment: Oh my god, @BoristheSpider you were right! I used the Thread's ClassLoader instead of the one from the class and it works fine.

Comment: Don’t sound so surprised - I sometimes get the right answer :P

Comment: I was fooled by the lack of an error and the thread not erroring, turns out the method just froze the other thread... I think you're right though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a new URLClassLoader because URLPathLoader appears to not be thread safe, and to set the Thread's context class loader to the URLClassLoader.
Kind of a work around with no explanation, but that's all I could figure out.